# Can I raise a quantum mechanical operator to another quantum mechanical operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-entanglement

The most complicated power operation for operators that I have seen is an operator (or a sum of operators) raised to a number. How can I handle an operator raised to another operator? Is this even possible? Also, are there any physics examples where such an operation may be necessary? Thanks.

Comment: how would you exponentiate an operator with something else than a number? This seems mathematically ill-defined.

Comment: okay, maybe you could have something like $x^{p}$, where $x$ and $p$ are both operators, be formally defined as $\exp(p\cdot log(x))$.

Comment: I have seen operators raised to a number and I have also seen numbers raised to an operator, both of which are mathematically possible. Hence, my guess was that an operator raised to another operator should be possible too.

Comment: I tried exp(p.log(x)), but does this always hold? My understanding is that this would depend on the commutator, [x,p]_.

Comment: I agree there is an ambiguity on whether p should appear to LHS or RHS of log(x), so yes, there would be some dependence on the commutator.

Comment: what is a physical example of a number raised to an operator?

Comment: BCH Formula (for number raised to an operator):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula

Commonly used in quantum optics derivations for expressing coherent states.

Comment: that is just exponentiation of an operator. I am talking about expression of the form $n^x$ where $n$ is some complex number and $x$ is an operator.

Comment: In a many-body bosonic system, an example operator would be the creation/annihilation operator raised to the bosonic number operator.

Comment: @wcc $e \in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: You may think of operators as generalized matrices, in which case, formally, any standard functional composition operation of matrices goes, including their featuring in exponents. Are you asking about technical consistency (checks, of course) or physical instances?

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos, I was asking about the technical consistency of exp(p⋅log(x)), i.e. whether this is mathematically correct for operators. I do have a physical instance where this occurs, as noted above.

Comment: Sure, $\exp (i\log x ~~\partial_x    )$ is a familiar, if not celebrated [Lie flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Shift_operator&action=edit&section=1) if you are interested in integrating 1/log ( *x* ) .

Answer (score 3):

Mathematically, if the logarithm of an operator $B$ exists, then you can construct another operator $\exp(\log(B) A)$ that you could call "$B^A$" if you wanted. However, it won't necessarily have any of the properties you might expect. For example, $B^A B^C \ne B^{A+C}$ except in very special circumstances. What's more $B^A B^A \ne B^{2A}$ basically unless $[\log(B),A] = 0$.

Another problem is that $\exp(\log(B)A) \ne \exp(A\log(B))$ in almost all cases, so it's not clear which of those two expressions we say is $B^A$.

In the comments you mentioned possibly raising a creation operator to the number operator. I imagine that what you want to do here is apply a different number of creation operators depending on the number of photons in the state. This would be much easier to accomplish with projection operators:
$$\sum_n (a^†)^n |n\rangle\langle n| \text{ or } \sum_n |2n\rangle\langle n|$$

Comment: There are simple conditions when such expressions make sense, i.e. if $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable (in particular, $[A,B]=0$). Then there is no problem with defining $B^A$ (after choosing a branch of analytic continuation if $B$ has negative eigenvalues for which $A$ has non-integral eigenvalues).